# Shell script on linux to run java class

Tags: linux, shell, selenium, jenkins

I am having to work on linux, (windows is my usual home)

I have a jenkins server and want to run some selenium scripts.

I have the following shell script , but its failing on not finding the paths ?

Can someone correct me if i have the correct names for Projectpath / Classpath and if i using the right syntax for directory path ?

```
Set ProjectPath = /home/myname/eclipse-workspace/jenkins_suite
echo %ProjectPath%
Set CLASSPATH = /home/myname/eclipse-workspace/jenkins_suite/lib/*:/home/mark.holloway/eclipse-workspace/jenkins_suite/bin/:
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG /home/myname/eclipse-workspace/jenkins_suite/testng.xml
```

Comment: This will never work on Linux, you are using Windows command line syntax.  https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is using Windows syntax, and you aren't being consistent with your ProjectPath (use the variable you already defined). It should look something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export ProjectPath="/home/myname/eclipse-workspace/jenkins_suite"
echo $ProjectPath
export CLASSPATH="$ProjectPath/lib/*:$ProjectPath/bin/*:."
echo $CLASSPATH
java org.testng.TestNG $ProjectPath/testng.xml
```